# Boost Matrix Dynamic Size Expansion

Tags: c++, boost, matrix

I am writing  a c++ program which uses boost library for matrix operations. I have a need were by i have to dynamically expand the size of the initial matrix.

Example:
if my matrix size was:

```
   matrix<float> m(3,3);
```

and later my matrix will expand and i'll need a 4*4 matrix. The naive approach i could think of is allocate a new matrix with size 4,4 and and copy all elements of 3*3 matrix to it. Isn't there any better way of doing this in boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, consider using the `resize()` function: "The existing elements of the matrix are preseved (*sic*) when specified."

Here is [an example code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_array/test/resize.cpp) from Boost.

This is one of ways.

```
matrix<int> A;  // Matrix size would be zero by zero
A.resize(2, 3);  // Matrix size became 2 by 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a matrix using the no arg constructor and call the resize method as needed?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm